# How to fix this error in Template Builder?

Tags: templating, template-builder

I have a Component template called "BC video" but if I call that in Component layout the Page publishing fails.

If I check in Template Builder the error is No Component Template was found with the name BC video. What may be the reason?

This is how I have called the template.

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="dfdVideoComponent" -->
  @@RenderComponentPresentation(dfdVideoComponent.ID,'${GetCTByName("BC Video")}' )@@
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

Comment: Can you give some more insights to what the package contains and how you set `dfdVideoComponent`? Also what does the custom function `GetCTByName` exactly do? Looks like it has a problem finding the template. I would also not suggest to hardcode these things in a template, it would be better to link the template through a parameter value, using a TCM URI or WebDAV path, since a name is easily changed.

Comment: I note you're reporting the error as `BC video` and the function (that you need to include the source for) tried to get `BC Video` - is case sensitivity at play here perhaps?

Comment: I have added the template properly. No issue of case sensitivity.

Comment: BC video add the Brightcove video to the page. When we click on the button BC video is played. dfdVideoComponent is the Brightcove Video ID

Comment: I have used same CT in other templates but only this template is giving this error in Template builder. Then i removed multimedia components in package handler TBB. After that page was published and the video is working fine but the image doesn't show the path as i have removed the related TBB. But if i keep that the page fails and i will not be able to publish.